# C# serial port class library

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a class library that uses serial port to transfer data across from a device using a proprietary protocol.

It worked fine when I was using as a windows form app.  The moment I converted it to a class lib, it ends after it processes the first bit of data.  Is there some threading that needs to be done to keep it from just returning it to the application that called it?  It needs to make sure all the data from the device has been gathered before returning control to the application which called it.

Here is the full code that is ending early:

```cpp
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
     using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

     namespace ValidataDex
     {



    public class DexLib
    {

        public Crc16 c = new Crc16();
        public Search s = new Search();

        const ushort polynomial = 0xA001;

        ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

        SerialPort port = null; // create port so it can be used and seen everywhere

        int good = 0;  // is dex good 

        public string myblock;

        public delegate void SetTextDeleg(byte[] text);
        public int count;

        public string stage = "initial";
        public string position = "";

        public string crcstuff = "";
        public byte[] crcdata;

        public int lastsent = 0;

        public int audit = 0;
        public char etboretx;
        public int gotenq = 0;
        public int x = 2;
        public int positiondetermined = 0;

        // Dex Commands
        public byte NUL = 0x00;
        public byte SOH = 0x01;
        public byte STX = 0x02;
        public byte ETX = 0x03;
        public byte EOT = 0x04;
        public byte ENQ = 0x05;
        public byte ACK = 0x06;
        public byte DLE = 0x10;
        public byte NAK = 0x15;
        public byte SYN = 0x16;
        public byte ETB = 0x17;
        public string Dex;
        public int rte=0;

        public string CHANGER_IS_SLAVE = "9252130100RR01L01";

        byte zero = 0x30;
        byte one = 0x31;

        public void Data_Received(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            count = port.BytesToRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[count];
            port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            // audit function activated by a file named debug residing in application directory
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            if (audit == 1 || File.Exists(path + @"\debug.txt"))
            {
                x = 0;
                foreach (byte b in data)
                {
                    audit_file(1, "stage:"+stage+" command:"+getdexcommand(b)+" pos det:"+positiondetermined);
                    //                textBox1.Text += getdexcommand(b);
                    x++;
                }
            }


            try
            {
                // wait for device to transmit a DLE to begin DEX
                if (data[0] == DLE || positiondetermined == 1)
                {
                     DexasMaster(data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                audit_file(2, ee.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You open the port and close it 4 lines later. Have you considered not closing it if you don't want it to close?

Comment: Yeah, and why do you attach an event handler to it just before you close it?  The handler will never fire.

Comment: if at all possible, make a simpler repro for the problem.  As Steve mentioned, you might just comment out the Close call and see how it behaves then.

Comment: since this is a class library would that make a difference?  I am calling this from another app.  The port.close wasnt there originally when I tested it.  It was a mistake for this post.

Comment: If you want accurate help, provide the code that is causing the problem; adding mistakes to the post just sidetracks readers..

Comment: its now processing more data but still ends before it is completely finished with its task

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to provide a Thread.Sleep long enough for all the data to process.  After that it worked like a charm.